# webpack converts html content into a url and tries to load it

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hi I am migrating from `systemjs` to `webpack` and I am having a weird issue. Webpack tries to load html assets by converting html contents into a url and tries load it.

directory structure

```
├── dist (ignored)
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   ├── kline.component.ts
│   │   ├── market-data.component.html
│   │   ├── market-data.component.ts
│   │   └── market-data.service.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── app.routes.ts
│   ├── entity
│   │   └── coinmarketcaptoken-entity.ts
│   ├── index.html
│   └── main.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {

    entry: {
        "app": "./src/main.ts"
    },

    output: {
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            { 
              test: /\.css$/, 
              loader: 'raw-loader',
              exclude: /\.async\.css$/
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "app-root",
    templateUrl: require("./app.component.html")
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

And here is screenshot from chrome console.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this my removing `require()` statements for `templateUrl` parameter from every angular component I had. So, a normal component would be like;

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "app-root",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

`angular2-template-loader` handles with `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` by adding require itself which is mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-template-loader